# cppUnit with Windows+minGW

Tags: c++, unit-testing, netbeans, mingw, cppunit

I'm using minGW with NetBeans to programming in C++. I know that I should use VS but it's defined to use NB.

Now I need to make unit tests. I tried to use cppUnit but I just can´t install it correctly. I tried to follow several tutorials and nothing.

From commands errors to NetBeans errors.

I have minGW installed with Msys.

Comment: I don't think "nothing" is a very good description of what goes wrong. Also, how do you know that you should use VS?

Comment: Good story, but was there a question? A review of [ask] seems warranted.

Comment: I tried to say that I can't install sucessfuly the cppunit.

The question is how do I install cppUnit on Windows with minGW compiler.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to use cppUnit but I just can´t install it correctly.

You can't install CppUnit out of the box, you have to build it before.

## Steps to do

1. Get the sourcecode
2. Build it
3. Install (depends on how you handle your probjects)
4. Add to your project

---

### Get the sourcecode

You can get the **sources** from the [**CppUnit website** at freedesktop.org](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/cppunit/).

Either **clone the git repository** or **download the release version**.

### Build it

The build is done using `configure` and `make`:

```
cd cppunit
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

Do ***not*** use the windows cmd for that, this may fail - use `sh` instead (eg. open a cmd and execute `sh` to get a mingw shell).

### Install

For installation on windows see **`INSTALL-WIN32.txt`** file within cppunit.

### Add to your project

You have to **add** the ***compiled binaries*** to the **linker**- and ***header paths*** to **compiler flags**. This strongly depends on how you build your project (= the one with your unit tests).

Since your question is tagged with **netbeans**, there's something realy cool:

You can add cppunit only as testing dependency. For a default NetBeans C/C++ this is done through a right click on "Test Files" -> Properties" -> "C(++) Compiler respectively Linker settings.

Unit tests can be added manually or through the "New File" Dialog.